# Assign a passed function through parameters to the onclick event of a dynamically created input type

Tags: javascript, jquery, event-handling, onclick, coffeescript

I'm calling a coffee-script from a js.erb file:

```
openModal("<%=escape_javascript render :partial=>"userbill/new" %>", "Check Bills", function(){alert("OK");});
```

In my HTML file,I have:

```
<input type= "button" id="left_modal_done" class= "btn btn-large btn-primary" style="margin-top: 5px;" value= "Done"></input>
```

Now the above coffee-script somewhat looks like this:

```
@openModal = (html_str, title, otherFunction) ->
  $("#left_modal_done").onclick = otherFunction //Not working
```

How can I assign the parameterized function(which is the alert function),to the onclick event of the input type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to assign the `onclick` property of a jQuery object, which doesn't make sense.

```
$("#left_modal_done").on('click', otherFunction);
```

is the behavior you're looking for.

Comment: For the sake of knowing,what if the function was passed as a string as in like:  openModal("<%=escape_javascript render :partial=>"userbill/new" %>", "Check Bills", "someFunction()");

Comment: Why would you do that?